# Texture Paint and UV map on render cycles disappears after restart blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, texture-painting

I have a problem when using the texture of paint on rendering cycles . I do the mapping texture and works properly . But when I restart the blender , the UV map and texture disappears and the material becomes black . So I have to paint the texture again. Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: Did you save the texture file before you restarted blender?

Comment: I saved All As blender Project.
I have to save the image separately?

Comment: Thank you! I saved the texture paint as image and it was ok.